# my multi boot can't boot to XP 'resumeobject' is missing

Tags: multi-boot, bcdedit

In my multi boot set up, booting to vista and 7 goes fine, but when I try to boot to XP, i get an error

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
File:   \NTLDR
Status: 0xc000000e
Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

See below. Clearly the **resumeobject** seems to be missing in the XP entry ("Real Mode Boot sector"), only I don't know how to restore it. Vista is on **C:**, Win7 is on **F:** (as is the bootmgr ??? ) and WinXP is on **E:**

**What I've tried:**
[1]
I've used about 5 windows discs, that is the Recovery Consoles from real XP install CD's and 3 virtual Recovery Consoles. All failed.
The real CD's work ONE time, but won't let me finish, I only got as far as
[b]fixboot E:[/b]

Then they shut the laptop down, I kid you not. On a next startup, all 5 CD's ask me for some Admin password that I've never added!

[2] I have VisualBCD and EasyBCD, but the most obvious things I tried there didn't solve the problem. So know I don't exactly know what to do with them.

[3] I CAN boot into XP with the FIX NTLDR workaround of http://milescomer.com/tinyempire.com/notes/ntldrismissing.htm, but it doesn't fix it permanently

***QUESTION:
How do I fix it permanently?***

`bcdedit /enum` output:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=F:
path                    \bootmgr
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
default                 {current}
displayorder            {current}
                        {812e27a9-27b7-11e4-8fb4-dfa8174ae8dc}
                        {812e27ac-27b7-11e4-8fb4-dfa8174ae8dc}
timeout                 30
resume                  No

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Vista
locale                  nl-NL
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {73d8b5bc-2764-11e4-b181-806e6f6e6963}

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {812e27a9-27b7-11e4-8fb4-dfa8174ae8dc}
device                  partition=F:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Daisy Etta
locale                  en-US
osdevice                partition=F:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {b8c234a4-27b0-11e4-b8b3-806e6f6e6963}

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {812e27ac-27b7-11e4-8fb4-dfa8174ae8dc}
device                  partition=E:
path                    \NTLDR
description             XP
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you perhaps hibernate Windows 7 and forcibly booted something else? Also, please note that “something” isn’t an error message. If you cannot be bothered to at least reproduce error message accurately, you cannot expect us to find a solution.

Comment: I did not hibernate windows 7, i moved my partitions and deleted the first 1 mb, which somehow i restored. but the xp stuff is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ["Dual-boot Repair" tool, the updated version for Windows 8.1](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-tool-for-windows-8.1-update.html)

It fixes automatically on click a dual-boot system based on Windows NT6 (Vista and later)
and fixes also NT5 booting (Windows XP, 2003).

```
Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {812e27ac-27b7-11e4-8fb4-dfa8174ae8dc}
device                  partition=E:
path                    \NTLDR
description             XP
```

THE CODE ABOVE IS COMPLETE BUL...IT (and I know the tool which creates it).

Microsoft has created the mechanism and the software for booting Windows 7/8 and XP and it must be followed if you don't want booting problems !

1. Delete "Real mode Boot Sector" Loader/Object (use Visual BCD or bcdedit)
2. Run "Automatic Repair" option from "Dual-boot Repair" tool. It will fix XP booting.
3. Eventually amend language settings (nl-NL) for boot manager and loaders if your Windows installations are in that language (en-US is the default for American English). Visual BCD or bcdedit can do this.

The rule is very, very simple:

**XP and Windows 7/Vista boot files must be on active partition (on MBR disk).**